# Is rotating bonds possible in mhchem?

Tags: rotating, chemistry, mhchem

I'm doing bonds using `mhchem` and I'm wondering if I can rotate a bond by X degrees. Is there a way?

Im using `mhchem` inline: `\ce{A\bond{3}B(<I want to insert an angle here>)\bond{2}C}`.

Thank you before all, sorry about language, but I'm kinda new with LyX and English is not my native language

Edit 1: By the way, I realized lurking on the site, that there is a better solution than `mhchem` using `chemfig`. But now I'm curious to know if there is a solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: That's not supported natively by mhchem. Can you show us what you have in mind (image or link)? If you can to it with LaTeX or Lyx you can insert it into an equation. If it's a standard notation (IUPAC, ACS or widely used), it can be added to mhchem.